How to avoid fake errors in Android Studio when Kotlin code is copy-pasted from the internet?
Sometimes, if I copy 100% valid Kotlin code from the internet and paste it into the Android Studio's Window Editor (mac version), the code will show a lot of errors. I have to fix these errors manually by re-entering the composable functions' names, properties or modifier's methods. By the way, in Xcode there's no such problem when I copy-paste Swift code.
Example (taken from https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/graphics/draw/overview):

Question – How to avoid this behavior in Android Studio?

I don't see anything wrong in Android Studio nagging about Canvas, size or drawRect() in the example. You can hover on an item highlighted in red and have suggested actions like importing android.graphics.Canvas and creating a variable called size. Automatically importing a class without user interaction could result in a wrong class being imported if there are several with the same name in various packages. And who knows should size be a local variable or a class member? Haven't used Xcode and Swift though, so maybe I don't know what I've missed. ;)

Thanks Markus! So, it turns out that if I create code step-by-step in an empty Jetpack Compose project, all the libraries are automatically pulled up, but if I use copy-paste, then I need to register the import manually? By the way, in this code you just need to import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas and everything will work.

That are no fake errors and you cannot avoid that because the code you copied is actually incomplete. It cannot be compiled and executed as it is, so Android Studio displays the errors that it found.
In your specific case the only thing that is missing is the import statement for Canvas. You can position the text cursor over Canvas and press Alt + Enter to see a list of possible fixes. As you can see there are multiple possible imports available. Which one to take? This cannot be automatically determined by Android Studio, but from the context you, as a person, have, you know that it looks like what you need is a composable function, so you would select androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas.
This cannot be avoided and, contrary to what you said in your question, you experience the same ambiguity if you manually type Canvas. Since Android Studio doesn't know what that is it displays a list of possible solutions, ordered by relevance. You probably just confirmed the first suggestion (which fortunately was the one you needed) by pressing Tab or Enter and didn't realize that that added the missing import statement behind the scenes.
The only thing you can actually influence is to tell Android Studio to automatically import all dependencies that are unambiguous, i.e. there is only one suggestion in the list. You can enable this in the settings by checking the box on Editor > General > Auto Import > Kotlin > Add unambiguous imports on the fly. This won't help you with your specific case (because there are multiple Canvas candidates), but it may help you in other situations by reducing the number of imports you have to manually select.
